# How can I reopen my app on certain activity after a soft-close

Tags: android, mobile, fragment

In my android project I have 2 fragments (A and B). If I soft-close the app while I'm in fragment A, when I re-open it, fragment B is displayed. When I re-open the app, why don't I get the fragment A? Any advice? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post some of your code and `manifest.xml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because fragment B would be your first fragment. you can use shared preferences and store which fragment is opened. override onResume() method on the main activity containing the fragments and get the variable in sharedpreferences and use pager.setCurrentItem(1) for fragment A or B whichever you want.

Comment: Will give it a go. Much apreciated